# $\int_{0}^{\pi} D_{n}(y)dy=\frac{1}{2}$ Dirichlet

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, dirichlet-series

I need to calculate that $\int_{0}^{\pi} D_{n}(y)dy=\frac{1}{2}$ with $D_{n}(y)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})y)}{\sin(\frac{y}{2})}$ from Dirichlet.

Now I tried to do this with the known that $D_{n}(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-1}^{n}e^{iky}$.

I tried to things but I never become 1/2.

1. First I tried to solve the somation and then integrate: $\int_{0}^{\pi} D_{n}(y)dy=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-1}^{n}e^{iky}dy=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi}(\frac{e^{-niy}-e^{iy(n+1)}}{1-e^{iy}})dy$. This integral doesn't converges so I did something wrong but I don't know what?

2. Second I tried to switch the integral and the sommetion and then solve it: $\int_{0}^{\pi} D_{n}(y)dy=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-1}^{n}e^{iky}dy=\int_{0}^{\pi} D_{n}(y)dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{iky}dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-1}^{n}\frac{1}{ik}(1-e^{-\pi i k})$. But this sometion will give $i\infty -i \infty$ so this doesn't work eather.

Can someone eplain me what I do wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a wrong definition of the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel). The proper one is

$$D_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-n}^n e^{ikx} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\sin \left(\frac{(n+1)x}{2}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}.$$

Based on that you have by switching $\int$ and $\sum$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}D_n(x) = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-n}^n e^{ikx} = 1.$$

as $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{ikx}=0 $ for $k\neq 0$ integer.

And as $D_n$ is even

$$\int_0^{\pi}D_n(x) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: How do you becom that the integral of Dn(x)=1. I always become something thats not integratble?

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{ikx} \ dx = 0$ for $k \neq 0$ integer.

Comment: Ow.. yes ofcourse.. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$2\sin\frac y2(\cos y + \cos2y+\cos3y+...+\cos ny)
= \sin\frac{(2n+1)y}2-\sin\frac y2 $$

Then

\begin{align}
 \int_{0}^{\pi} D_{n}(y)dy=&\frac{1}{2\pi}
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin\frac{(2n+1)y}{2}}{\sin \frac y2}{\rm d}y\\
=&\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\pi(1+2\cos x + 2\cos2x+...+2\cos nx){\rm d}x\\
=&\frac1{2\pi}[\pi + (0+0+...+0)]=\frac12 \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You have to do summation from -n to +n when identifying Dirichlet kernel, though *your closed expression for the kernel is correct*: $D_{n}(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{iky}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})y)}{\sin(\frac{y}{2})}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\sin(\frac{(2n+1)y}{2})}{\sin(\frac{y}{2})}$

$D_{n}(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{iky}=\frac{1}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{iky}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-1}^{-n}e^{iky}=\frac{1}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{iy}(1-e^{iyn})\frac{1}{1-e^{iy}}+\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-iy}(1-e^{-iyn})\frac{1}{1-e^{-iy}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{e^\frac{iy}{2}-e^\frac{-iy}{2}-e^\frac{iy}{2}-e^{-iy(n+\frac{1}{2})}-e^\frac{iy}{2}+e^{iy(n+\frac{1}{2})}}{e^\frac{iy}{2}-e^\frac{-iy}{2}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})y)}{\sin(\frac{y}{2})}$

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but I don't really think that you understood my question. I didn't ask for the kernel but I was trying to prove that the integral was 1/2.

Comment: But still thank you for letting me see how you can becom the kernel out of a summation.

Comment: @questmath, you are provided with the right explanation (above); I just wanted to point out the right close form for the kernel  - to avoid possible confusion (because the typo was made in the explanation when provided the close form. I guess the best way to make sure is to provide straightforward calculations :)